# OpenCV-Python installation - CMake error missing vtkRenderingOpenGL [16.04]

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, cmake, opencv

I'm trying to install `Python-OpenCV` in Python3 on my  LTS system following [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) guide.

When I try to run CMake:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I get the following error:

```
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 54 (504)
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   No package 'libdc1394-2' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   No package 'libdc1394' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/matt/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/matt/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/matt/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:120 (message):
  Requested modules not available:

    vtkRenderingOpenGL
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKConfig.cmake:89 (vtk_module_config)
  cmake/OpenCVDetectVTK.cmake:6 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:597 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/matt/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/matt/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I've followed the guide completely up until this point so I'm not sure what is wrong.

I've looked around to try and fix the missing package `vtkRenderingOpenGL` and followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170869/cmake-could-not-find-opengl-in-ubuntu) post from stackoverflow. I'm sure that I've installed this in the past and so I get:

```
sudo apt -y install freeglut3-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
freeglut3-dev is already the newest version (2.8.1-2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

**Any and all help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking advice given from the OpenCV community forum ([post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/130153/python-opencv-installation-cmake-error-missing-vtkrenderingopengl-ubuntu-1604/)).

Add this to CMake options:

```
-D WITH_VTK=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_viz=OFF
```

*"opencv_viz is the only opencv module, that depends on vtk, and you cannot use it from python"*

Therefore it is fine to just disable it all together and after doing so CMake completes.